# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\global.txt' i am executing this on google collaboration ipython notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to open a text file that is stored in D drive but python is not able to locate it

```
 f=open('D:\global.txt','r',errors = 'ignore')
    raw=f.read()
    raw=raw.lower()
    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    sent_tokens=nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)
    word_tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(raw)

**Error generated is**:
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-808f13a51694> in <module>()
----> 1 f=open('D:\global.txt','r',errors = 'ignore')
      2 raw=f.read()
      3 raw=raw.lower()
      4 nltk.download('punkt')
      5 nltk.download('wordnet')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\global.txt'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have global.txt on your disk D? I copied code and it works.

Comment: If its a issue of specifying the file path based upon your platform (i.e. Linux vs. Windows vs Mac), you can checkout [The easy way to deal with file paths on Windows, Mac and Linux](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)

Comment: Use `os.path.join('D:', 'global.txt')`

Comment: @Mortimer yes it is present in my  disk D i dont know why it is not working.Please help me with this

Comment: @DarrylG im using windows 10 and im using google collaboration for this code ipython notebook for this purpose

Comment: You are using Google Colab to run this code?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes

Comment: Collab runs in a remote server, it cannot access the files in your hard drive.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro oh so is there any other way that i can attach it

Comment: Yes but that is a completely different question, please update your question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro please let  me know the other  method.I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("D:/global.txt", "r") as f:
    raw = f.read()
    raw = raw.lower()
    nltk.download("punkt")
    nltk.download("wordnet")
    sent_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)
    word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw
```

Edit: Is the code run on a remote location? Maybe you're getting confused on where the file global.txt should be.

Comment: yes its being run on google collaboration ipython notebook

Comment: I'm not familiar with google collaboration. But if it is run on a remote location then you are referencing the D drive on that location, not your own D drive.